# print varchar with line start at certain index

Tags: sql

Hi I want to print something like that

```
                I will start from there 
test this phrase
```

so I did the following

```
declare @x varchar(max)
select @x = LEFT(' '+'I will start from there',LEN('test this phrase')+ LEN('I will start from there'))+ CHAR(10) + 'test this phrase'

print @x
```

the output is

```
 I will start from there
test this phrase
```

the first line not started from the beginning of the second line , `left` should do the trick but am not sure what's wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [**SPACE**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187950.aspx) function as below

```
declare @x varchar(100)
select @x = LEFT(SPACE(LEN('test this phrase')+1)+'I will start from there',LEN('test this phrase')+ LEN('I will start from there'))+ CHAR(10) + 'test this phrase'

print @x
```